# how to get the image topic from the other computer with WiFi

Tags: network, stream, image, multiple-machines, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I have opened the webcam with usb_cam successfully, and I can see the image_raw topic running. However, I want to get the image_stream from the other computer. How could I do to subscribe the image_raw topic from the other computer'ROS with WiFi？
publisher: indigo ubuntu 14.04
subscriber: virtubox on mac ubuntu14.04.3 indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234415/how-to-get-the-image-topic-from-the-other-computer-with-wifi/) by [Joy.Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26415/joy.lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As long as both computers are on the same network, you just need to start a ROS master on one, and tell both computers which ROS_MASTER_URI to use.

There is a tutorial that has more detail [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0